# How do I read the project version number stored in the pyproject.toml file from within the tox.ini file?

Tags: python, tox, pyproject.toml

I want to include an `upload` environment in my `tox.ini` file.
But, that requires resolving the project version dynamically; something like:

```yaml
[testenv:upload]
basepython = python3.11
skip_install = true
deps =
    twine
commands =
    twine upload dist/foo-{[project]version}.tar.gz dist/foo-{[project]version}-py3-none-any.whl
```

But, that syntax doesn't work:

```
% tox -e upload
upload: commands[0]> twine upload 'dist/foo-{[project]version}.tar.gz' 'dist/foo-{[project]version}-py3-none-any.whl'
ERROR    InvalidDistribution: Cannot find file (or expand pattern): 'dist/foo-{[project]version}.tar.gz'
```

**What is the correct syntax, in the `tox.ini` file, for reading the project version from the `pyproject.toml` file?**

Comment: Although I am not too familiar with the tools, looks like tox [supports different formats](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#configuration-discovery) in priority order. Is there any reason why you want to have both `tox.ini` and `pyproject.toml`?

Answer (score 0):

Tox itself does not have a global variable called `project` and if you want to get the project version from pyproject.toml, You could do this

- Explicitly set the project version within your tox file, but that would involve having to change project version in two places. You can use tox `setenv` command to set the version.

```html
[testenv]
setenv =
    VERSION=0.01

[testenv:upload]
basepython = python3.11
skip_install = true
deps =
    twine
commands =
    twine upload dist/foo-{env:VERSION}.tar.gz dist/foo-{env:VERSION}-py3-none-any.whl
```